# entity has two relationships one-to-one and one-to-many at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities `Employee`, `Branch`

```
public class Branch
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}


public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }

}
```

each branch has many departments, each department has many employees, each employee belong to one department and one branch

the database scheme should look like this :

```
Branch     : Id , Name , ManagerId
Department : Id , Name , ManagerId
Employee   : Id , Name , DepartmentId , BranchId, ManagerId #(department manager)
```

I want to have **OneToOne** relationship for `Branch` with `Employee` (Manager), and **OneToMany** relationship for `Branch` with `Employee` (Employees Of Branch)

right now when I try to add migrations, it fails with

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
> property 'Branch.Manager' of type 'Employee'

I understand the issue, but not able to solve it.

Comment: What's the difference between an Employee Manager and a Branch Manager?  Also you shouldn't include the Branch in the Employee table as you can get that by going through the Department.  Otherwise you create the possibility of an Employee having a different Branch from the Department's Branch.

Comment: @juharr each employee has a manager (the manager of the department that he belong to), each branch has many departments and also has one manager.
I can handle the possibility of an Employee having a different Branch from the Department's Branch.

Answer (score 2):

This design is too de-normalized which leads to a risk of invalid associations, and more explicit mapping needed for relationships.

For instance, if a Branch has a Manager, and a collection of employees, then an employee can get their manager via the Branch. I.e.

```
employee.Branch.Manager
```

The issue with having Manager on both Employee and Branch is there is no way to ensure that employee.Manager and employee.Branch.Manager are always pointing at the same person. (where they should always be the same person)

A Department may have a manager as well, but this would be expected to be a higher level manager where each branch has a manager that reports to a department manager.

EF will sometimes get confused trying to work out associations between entities by convention if you don't specify the FK relationship between the FK property and navigation property. From memory, EF convention uses the Property ***type***, not the property name as the default expected key name.

So for instance given a property

```
public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
```

You might expect EF to work out to expect a FK to be "ManagerId" but instead it would attempt to use "EmployeeId" by default based on the type `Employee` not the property name.  This is why you would need to explicitly point it at "ManagerId" as the FK using the `ForeignKey` attribute or better, using `.Map(x => x.MapKey("ManagerId"))` or EF Core Shadow Properties to avoid declaring FK properties in your entities alongside the navigation properties.